# What's wrong with this code? Fibonacci series

Tags: c++, fibonacci, dev-c++

It should print the Fibonacci series up until a position, but it just prints 1 1 2, even if I ask for more than the first three elements. How can I fix this?

```
#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::cin;

int main()
{
    cout << "Enter a number: ";
    int number;
    cin >> number;
    int count = 1;
    int a = 1;                  //The first number of the Fibonacci's serie is 1
    int b = 1;                  //The second number of the Fibonacci's serie is 2
    while (count <= number)
    {
        if (count < 3)
            cout << "1 ";
        else
        {
            number = a + b;     //Every number is the sum of the previous two
            cout << number << " ";
            if (count % 2 == 1)
                a = number;
            else
                b = number;
        }
        count++;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `number` as the maximum number of loop iterations here:

```
while (count <= number)
```

But then inside the loop you're using the same variable as the current Fib value to output for each iteration.

```
number = a + b;     //Every number is the sum of the previous two
cout << number << " ";
```

That's causing the loop to terminate prematurely. You need to pick different variable names for these two different values.

Answer (score 1):

It is like swapping the variable's values.
You're using the number as limitation but in the loop you're using the same variable that is creating a logical error. Do the following changes and you're done (Y).

```
int main()
{
cout << "Enter a number: ";
int number;
cin >> number;
int count = 1;
int a = 1;                  //The first number of the Fibonacci's serie is 1
int b = 1; 
int i = 1;                 //The second number of the Fibonacci's serie is 2
while (i <= number)
{
    if (i < 3)
        cout << "1 ";
    else
    {
        count = a + b;     //Every number is the sum of the previous two
        a = b;
        b = count;
        cout << count << " ";
    }
    i++;
}

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -2):

You can try this code:

```
int main()
{
    int n, t1 = 0, t2 = 1, nextTerm = 0;

    cout << "Enter the number of terms: ";
    cin >> n;

    cout << "Fibonacci Series: ";

    for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
      // Prints the first two terms.
        if(i == 1)
        {
            cout << " " << t1;
            continue;
        }
        if(i == 2)
        {
            cout << t2 << " ";
            continue;
       }
        nextTerm = t1 + t2;
        t1 = t2;
        t2 = nextTerm;

        cout << nextTerm << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It might be really helpful, especially for future users to actually say why this works compared to the other answers. Bills answer has less code, but actually tells OP why his post actually works.